# Pull Specific Data From Multidimensional PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pull just the 'message' data from each of these arrays contained within this multidimensional array, but can't figure out how to get deep enough in the array to pull it. The page I'm using is returning the data this way, so there is no way I can edit it to be returned differently.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [revision_cache] => stdClass Object
            (
                [revision] => 14
                [email] => email@email.com
                [changed_dirs] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [account_id] => 133673
                [message] => Deleted unneeded help desk files.
                [hash_id] => 
                [author] => asdfasfd
                [too_large] => 
                [user_id] => 308011
                [repository_id] => 401677
                [changed_files] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => hdeskdelete.php
                                [1] => delete
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => hdeskrespond.php
                                [1] => delete
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => hdesktickets.php
                                [1] => delete
                            )

                    )

                [time] => 2012/08/13 17:01:58 -0500
                [changed_properties] => 
            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [revision_cache] => stdClass Object
            (
                [revision] => 13
                [email] => email@email.com
                [changed_dirs] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [account_id] => 133673
                [message] => Major updates and restyling of Help Desk system.
                [hash_id] => 
                [author] => asdfasdfasdf
                [too_large] => 
                [user_id] => 308011
                [repository_id] => 401677
                [changed_files] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => members/hdeskdelete.php
                                [1] => delete
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => helpdesk.php
                                        [1] => members/helpdesk.php
                                        [2] => 3
                                    )

                                [1] => copy
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => members/hdeskrespond.php
                                [1] => delete
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => members/hdesktickets.php
                                [1] => delete
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => hdeskdelete.php
                                        [1] => members/hdeskdelete.php
                                        [2] => 3
                                    )

                                [1] => copy
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => members/helpdesk.php
                                [1] => delete
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => hdeskrespond.php
                                        [1] => members/hdeskrespond.php
                                        [2] => 3
                                    )

                                [1] => copy
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => hdesktickets.php
                                        [1] => members/hdesktickets.php
                                        [2] => 3
                                    )

                                [1] => copy
                            )

                    )

                [time] => 2012/08/13 17:01:20 -0500
                [changed_properties] => 
            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
...
```

So basically, this block of arrays goes on for some time. I only need to pull the value each time that 'message' is the key. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through all elements in the array while checking if the message is there, something like this:

```
foreach($inputArray as $element)
{
    if( ! empty($element->revision_cache->message)
    {
        //do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: PERFECT. It did exactly what I needed it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$message = $arrayname[0]["revision_cache"]["message"];
```

Comment: The sub-elements are *not* arrays, they're objects

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach($array as $item){
   echo $item->revision_cache->message."<br>";
}
```